# Request works on Postman/Browser, but it doesn't work with axios

Tags: axios, postman, httprequest

I make a `GET` request to this URL: `https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT`, if I use Postman or just paste it on my browser, it works, but if I use `axios` like this, it fails:

```
 try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      'https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT'
    );

    console.log('data', data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Something went wrong:`, err);
  }
```

You can test it on this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-test-axios-njrh3z?file=index.js

Can someone explain me why please?

Comment: its a CORS error, you can see that when using `fetch` in the console

`fetch('https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT');` ... `Promise {<pending>}
request-works-on-postman-browser-but-it-doesnt-work-with-axios:1 Access to fetch at 'https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Answer (score 0):

Mexc open api required a apikey for use they api.

https://mxcdevelop.github.io/apidocs/#api-key

If you log data response in axios, you will see this in console.

```
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;api&#46;mexc&#46;com&#47;api&#47;v3&#47;depth&#63;" on this server.<P>\n
```

Let get an api key then use them api

Comment: For that endpoint it is not necessary, it is a public endpoint. I also have seen that problem, but it is not related to the API key.